# Strange behaviours of <?php when send to the browser in XMLHTTP response

Tags: php, html, pre

Trying to print on my webpage this:

```
<?php  

// Usage: $master=new WebSocket("localhost",12345);

class WebSocket{
  var $master;
  var $sockets = array();
  var $users   = array();
  var $debug   = false;

  function __construct($address,$port){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush();

    $this->master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");
```

Getting only:

```
master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");
```

!!

In same time I can see in Chrome Inspector Network tab, that it was delivered to the browser correctly.

When I inspected PRE element I see this:

```
<pre><!--?php  

// Usage: $master=new WebSocket("localhost",12345);

class WebSocket{
  var $master;
  var $sockets = array();
  var $users   = array();
  var $debug   = false;

  function __construct($address,$port){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush();

    $this--->master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");

</pre>
```

Who comment out the code and why, and the main question how to stop it!?

Comment: Chrome is known for commenting out visible PHP, a security "feature" I believe.

Comment: your http server have no handler for php

Comment: Did you name the file _something_.php?

Comment: @AlexLunix , also happening in Firefox.

Comment: @eicto , "your http server have no handler for php" - what that suppose to mean?

Comment: @Barmar, What file you talking about? This chunk of PHP saved in DB and transferred to the user to display.

Comment: I didn't realize you intentionally sent the PHP script to the browser. Usually PHP scripts are intended to be run on the server. That's eicto's excuse as well, I think.

Comment: @xchg.ca check your webserver config, it not process php files, that all i can tell to you :) what httpd server do you use ? in case of apache install and configure mod_php,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<?php` with `&lt;?php` and replace `$this->` with `$this-&gt;` and you'll get the intended result.  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yVJDb/)

In general, literal angle brackets and ampersands in HTML should be replaced with entities to avoid misinterpretation. In this case, Chrome assumes that receiving literal PHP code was a mistake, not intentional, and turns it into a comment. I can't find any documentation saying that it does this, but it's obvious what's going on.

Comment: That assumes the script creating the AJAX response is written in PHP.